# Text hover popups do not want to use max-width

Tags: html, css

Best illustrated with examples

Example 1 (http://jsfiddle.net/65CU9/1/):

HTML:

```
blah blah blah <span style="position:relative;">@blah<span class="my_popup">lots of text could go here but i cant let it be too long omg help me this is out of control ALWAYS I WANNA BE WITH YOU AND MAKE BELIEVE WITH YOU AND LIVE IN HAR-MO-NY HA-MO-NY</span></span> blah blah
```

CSS:

```
.my_popup {
    display:            none;
    position:           absolute;
    background-color:   white;
    border:             1px solid black;
    left:               0px;
    padding:            4px;
    max-width:          256px;
}
span:hover .my_popup {
    display:            block;
    white-space:        nowrap;
    z-index:            2;
}
```

Example 2 (http://jsfiddle.net/65CU9/3/):

HTML

```
blah blah blah <span style="position:relative;">@blah<span class="my_popup">removing 'white-space:nowrap' and using a fixed 'width' solves this, but only for large amounts of text that spill past the popup's width</span></span> blah blah
<br>&nbsp;<br>
however, when we try to use small <span style="position:relative;">@amount<span class="my_popup">wat</span></span> of text with a fixed 'width', we so fat
```

CSS

```
.my_popup {
    display:            none;
    position:           absolute;
    background-color:   white;
    border:             1px solid black;
    left:               0px;
    padding:            4px;
    width:          256px;
}

span:hover .my_popup {
    display:            block;
    z-index:            2;
}
```

There does not seem to be an obvious option for the text to be allowed to expand the popup and also obey max-width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this isn't possible.  Best compromise solution I have is to add `overflow-x:auto;`.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your problem correctly, could you set a max-width: of whatever you want and then set width to auto?

example:

```
.my_popup {
display:            none;
position:           absolute;
background-color:   white;
border:             1px solid black;
left:               0px;
padding:            4px;
max-width:          256px;
width:              auto;
}
```

Comment: @Hamster sorry missed that part, on that example take out the nowrap

Comment: It's no different than removing 'width', though.